# Could not fetch URL: https://storage.googleapis.com in java gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to **migrate** from deprecated Google Cloud Storage API to Google Cloud Storage Client Library. It will be a simple reading of existing pdf files. However, I keep getting time out error with this error message:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry: RetryHelper(462.8 ms, 2 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.SimpleGcsInputChannelImpl$1@13ed7d8): 
    Attempt 2 failed, sleeping for 16 ms:
       java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: 
           https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket]/[object_name]
```

There is also similar question on python side:

[Appengine cloudstorage python library timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759843/appengine-cloudstorage-python-library-timeout-issue)

I'm still not sure if there will be a similar fix on java side. Should I get the latest source and compile it?

Comment: The application has the permission to Read the object you are trying to read? However, the Fetch URL APIs are not the best option for read a GCS object, the library provides itself a method for reading objects. You can try using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18340201/1013317

Comment: Sometimes just 2 retries does not provide enough backoff. What does it do if you use the default retry policy?